# Java Multithread code gives error-IllegalMonitorException

Tags: java, multithreading, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I was trying some concepts of multithreading learned recently but was not able to run it.

It gives IlleagalMonitorStateException but does not figure out the error why it is happening.

So about code-2 threads-reference names-filler & writter both are sharing an arraylist-filler is filling arraylist with integer(but will fill it upto 30) and after each number is added by filler and writter thread read the arraylist get the item writes it to file remove it from arraylist. For better understanding comment is added to code.

```
package com.utsav.pratice;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //shared arraylist-synchronized
        ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        //writter will write to this file numbers added to arraylist by filler and than will remove it from arraylist
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("Numbers.txt");
        //filler will mark it true after completing all numbers
        final boolean[] numbersCompleted = {false};

        Thread filler=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //1-30 numbers one by one will be written to Arraylist
                for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
                    synchronized (integerArrayList) {
                        //if arraylist is not empty that means writter not performed on arraylist hence invoking wait to release lock so writter could perform
                        while(!integerArrayList.isEmpty()){
                            try {
                                wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        //so arraylist is empty now lets fill it,notify that releasing lock and than put thread to sleep
                        integerArrayList.add(i);
                        System.out.println("Number added");
                        if(i==30){
                            numbersCompleted[0] =true;}
                        notifyAll();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Numbers adding completed");
            }
        });

        Thread writter=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                //if numbers are completed than nothing to write come out of loop
                while(!numbersCompleted[0]) {
                    synchronized (integerArrayList) {
                        //if arraylist is empty than its time for filler to work hence putting thread to wait so lock could be released for filler
                        while (integerArrayList.isEmpty()){
                            try {
                                wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        //so arraylist is not empty now lets write it & than remove it from arraylist,notify that releasing lock and than put thread to sleep
                        try (DataOutputStream fileWritter = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(file));) {
                            fileWritter.writeInt(integerArrayList.get(0));
                            System.out.println("Random number written");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        integerArrayList.remove(0);
                        notifyAll();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("File written completely");
            }
        });

        //starting both threads-2cases filler takes the key-ok(will fill & wait) or filler takes the key(will wait since will be empty)
        writter.start();
        filler.start();
```

Comment: [Read the Javadoc of `notifyAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()): "[Throws] IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.". You're invoking `notifyAll()` without synchronizing on `this`.

Comment: The best concept to learn in multithreading is: don't try to use the low-level multithreading methods on `Object`; use higher-level constructs from `java.util.concurrent` instead. They will give a much more gentle and useful introduction to multithreading in Java.

Comment: Note that `final boolean[] numbersCompleted = {false};` is not a reliable way to signal completion between the threads. There is no guarantee that updates to `numbersCompleted[0]` will be visible in the other thread. You should use an `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: Thanks i get to know the reason so it means that wait, notify and notifyall are supposed to be used between synchronized methods of a single class who are invoked together on a single object and methods are waiting for lock to be free on the synchronized object. And in my case in place of wait i have to write a code which make synchronized arraylist to be free so one of those who are waiting on the arraylist object monitor can start working and in place of notifyall a code is required to notify those who are waiting on arraylist object monitor. If you can help me on this Can it be achieved ??

Comment: No it doesn't. Read the exception again, and then look up its documentation.

Comment: @EJP sorry sir i didn't get on which quote you are replying on.

Comment: @AndyTurner now i got it actually i was in a impression that if i use wait() in synchronized block than it will release the lock of the object which is synchronized it came from like in a method body we add synchronized keyword and it symbolize "synchronized(this)" and if we add "wait();" instead of "this.wait()" in method body than it releases the lock of "this" object similarly i thought will work in the case of "synchronized(arrayListObject)". Anyways thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
synchronized (integerArrayList)
```

You are synchronizing on your **list**.

But you are waiting/notify on **this** of your anonymous thread objects! And as the **very first** information in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) says:

*Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.*

So things should work when you change those to

```
integerArrayList.wait()
```

for example (all usage of wait/notify/...) !

And hint: don't do things like

```
final ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

just go for

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Simply do **not** use the concrete impl class type as type of your variable; and also not as part of its name!